# Groovy: How to call annotated methods

Tags: java, groovy

I have an annotation @MyAnnotation sticked on the top of some methods in a couple of classes like these:

```
FirstClass {
    @MyAnnotation
    doSomethingWith(String text) { println 'text from first class' }

    @MyAnnotation
    doSomethingWith(Foo foo) { println 'foo from first class' }

    @MyAnnotation
    doAlsoSomethingWith(Bar bar) { println 'bar from first class' }    
}

SecondClass {
    @MyAnnotation
    doOtherStuffWith(Foo foo) { println 'foo from second class' }    
}

GenericGateway {    
    execute(instancedParam) {
        // call something passing an instance of "Foo" class
        // call something passing an instance of "Bar" class
        // call something passing an instance of "String" class
    }   
}
```

Now I am expecting that every method annotated with @MyAnnotation and same method's arguments (not caring of the method's name self) it is called at runtime from the "gateway" based on the instanced parameter.

```
// Example:

gateway.execute(new Foo(...))
gateway.execute('something')
gateway.execute(new Bar(...))

// I am expecting to see:

foo from first class
foo from second class
text from first class
bar from first class
```

If I am going to solve it with Java I will probably end up to use "reflection" API and mapping the method names somewhere with some strategy. Is there a way to do it more "elegantly" with Groovy?

Comment: Where are you stucked now? Did you google and why you have a tag groovy and java?

Comment: The tag groovy is due to the fact I am trying to solve it using "groovy" only. Groovy gives you a lot of metaprogramming alternatives respect to Java, so I am wondering if there is something that works better with this kind of problem.

Comment: Why do you want to rely on an annotation in this case instead of a common interface?

Comment: because if u create 2000 methods with different signatures u have to create 2000 methods signatures across different interfaces that espress the same concepts, and then associate all these interfaces to the same gateway statically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not aware of any shortcut to ease Java's reflection API. But you can always benefit from Groovy's terseness:

```
import java.lang.reflection.*
import java.lang.annotation.*

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@interface A {}

class Annotated {
  @A def a() { "a" }
  @A def b() { "b" }
  def c() { "c" }
}

ann = new Annotated()

methods = ann.class.methods.findAll { it.getAnnotation(A) }

assert methods.size() == 2

assert methods.collect { it.invoke(ann) } == ["a", "b"]
```