# Groovy execute code using custom annotation

Tags: groovy, annotations, annotation-processing

I would like to execute a function (with parameters) through an annotation tag in a groovy script.
If we execute a method in our groovy script with this annotation it would print in the console (stderr) a custom message like:

`warning: '<function_name>' is deprecated [[Use '<Deprecated.instead>' instead.][More info: '<Deprecated.more_info>']]`

So, I have created a custom annotation like this

```groovy
    public @interface Deprecated {
        public String instead() default null
        public String more_info() default null
    }
```

The goal is to use it like this:

```groovy
def new_call() {
    //new version of the method
}

@Deprecated(instead="new_call")
def call() {
    //do something
}
```

In my example, it would output like this:

```shell
warning: 'call' is deprecated. Use 'new_call' instead.
```

I saw this post [Groovy: How to call annotated methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27469305/groovy-how-to-call-annotated-methods), it's over 7 years old now but looks good so i'll look deeper.
I saw also [Delegate.deprecated](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/Delegate.html#deprecated()) but i'm not sure if that's what i want

I'm not sure I am doing right. So if you have any advice or suggestions, I'll be happy to hear you.

Comment: Neither of the links you provide are addressing what you want. What they have in common is annotations but you have a specific need, not accounted for in those discussions. There are a number of ways to accomplish what you want but knowing the context in which you want to do it may be helpful. For example, one way to do it is to write an AST Transformation that analyzes all your calls and injects the logging at compile time, or if you are doing this in the context of a Spring or Grails or Micronaut app, you could easily use AOP.  Different solutions will make sense for different contexts.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Indeed I was a little lost in my research and it made me a little confused. I'm not familiar with AOP, I'll look into it more. Thank you for these clarifications!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Simple AOP Approach

This is very-very basic implementation with groovy out-of the box.

**Deprecated Annotation**

```
@Target([ElementType.METHOD])
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface Deprecated {

    String instead() default 'null'

    String more_info() default 'null'

}
```

**Class which should get this functionality**

The class has to implement `GroovyInterceptable` - `invokeMethod`.

```
class SomeClass implements GroovyInterceptable {

    @Override
    def invokeMethod(String name, args) {
        DeprecatedInterception.apply(this, name, args)
    }

    def new_call() {
        println('new_call invoked')
    }

    @Deprecated(instead = 'new_call', more_info = '... the reason')
    def depr_call() {
        println('depr_call invoked')
    }

}
```

**Interception Util**

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod

class DeprecatedInterception {

    static apply(Object owner, String methodName, Object args) {
        MetaMethod metaMethod = owner.metaClass.getMetaMethod(methodName, args)
        Deprecated d = extractAnnotation(metaMethod)
        if (d) {
            println("warning: '$methodName' is deprecated. Use '${d.instead()}' instead. More info: '${d.more_info()}'")
        }
        // handle methods with var-args 
        metaMethod.isVargsMethod() ?
                metaMethod.doMethodInvoke(owner, args) :
                metaMethod.invoke(owner, args)
    }

    static Deprecated extractAnnotation(MetaMethod metaMethod) {
        if (metaMethod instanceof CachedMethod) {
            metaMethod.getCachedMethod()?.getAnnotation(Deprecated)
        } else {
            null
        }
    }

}
```

**Simple Test**

Just check that no exceptions/errors..

```
class TestWarnings {

    @Test
    void test() {
        new SomeClass().with {
            new_call()
            depr_call()
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
new_call invoked
warning: 'depr_call' is deprecated. Use 'new_call' instead. More info: '... the reason'
depr_call invoked
```

##### Disclaimer

This should work for most cases, but has some limitations:

- will not work for static methods (unless invoked on Object instance)
- you have to implement `GroovyInterceptable` per each class, to apply
- you might faced with some side-effects in some groovy syntax or features (at least I've found the issue with vararg methods invocation, but this already fixed)

So this should be tested and potentially improved before widely using for some production projects.

---

**Other options**:

Shortly, because implementation might be more complex (not sure, at least I not able to provide some example in a short time), but potentially this is more solid.

- Adding AST Transformations.
- Use some AOP library.

Comment: Like I said to @Jeff Scott Brown, I'm not familiar with AOP but I understand better now thanks to you. Your code is really simple, clear and easily understandable. Thank you for this example, it really helped me a lot!

Comment: @Sunchock thanks for your feedback. Once this'll become more familiar, it's easier to research and understand some more complex solutions. So, good luck!